# Gcc compiler C string assignment issue

Tags: c, string, gcc, variable-assignment, tcc

I wrote this code because I'm having a similar problem in a larger program I'm writing. For all I know the problem is the same so I made this small example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int x;
    char * val;
}my_struct;

int main()
{
    my_struct me = {4, " "};
    puts("Initialization works.");
    me.val[0] = 'a';
    puts("Assignment works.");
    puts(me.val);
    puts("Output works.");
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with tcc (Tiny C Compiler) it compiles and executes fine. But using GCC 4.6.0 20110513 (prerelease) it compiles, however, when I execute it I only get past "Initialization works." before getting a segfault.

What am I doing wrong? Is it my code or my GCC compiler?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-does-simple-c-code-receive-segmentation-fault/164258#164258) says it well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code.  ANSI permits string constants to be read-only, and this is encouraged because it means they can be shared system-wide across all running instances of a program; `gcc` does so unless you specify `-fwritable-strings`, while `tcc` makes them writable (probably because it's easier).

Comment: Thanks. So I make it writable? I have to create an array of characters and link to that rather than a pointer to a string?

Comment: @Tnelsond: you shouldn't rely on that behavior, and instead *not* initialize a `char*` from a `const char[]` (which degenerates in `const char*`). Use a copy instead.

Comment: So I should use the strcpy function from a string literal to make a modifiable string?

Comment: @tnelsond: Ideally, yes.  C strings are... primitive.  (Strings are the primary reason I stopped using C for much of anything.  Stick to C++ strings whenever possible.)

Answer (score 0):

`val` is an points to read only location.

```
char *readOnly = "Data in read only location" ;
```

`readOnly` pointing data cannot be modified.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have pointed out, `val` is pointing at a string constant.  Try

```
my_struct me = {4, malloc(2)};
```

and remember to check if `val` is `NULL` if you're using this in a real program.

Comment: Oh so that's how I'd do it. So I have to free malloced string afterwards right? Or will it free itself on exit from the program?

Comment: @Tnelsond - You need to explicitly deallocate the resources using `free`.

Comment: I need to free it even if my program is exiting? If that's the case, would it be better for me to just create an array of characters and link to that rather than allocating memory with malloc?

Comment: @Tnelsnod you don't have to call `free` if your program is exiting, but you said you were giving us an example of code that was used in a more complicated program, in that case you should beware of possibly memory leaks if you don't free your memory.